# Plans for integrated (and free) VPN support from within Tor Browser?

Tags: vpn

Are there any plans to provide integrated (and free) VPN support from within the Tor Browser?  I am interested to see if something similar to this functionality provided by the Opera browser (DEV 39) is in work...

---

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe the following statements are true WRT VPNs and Tor:

Trusted VPNs provide encryption/authentication functionality to protect packet payload content for a given session connection but do nothing to 'anonymize' traffic routing information. VPNs are data-centric from a security/privacy standpoint and cannot 'help once the active connection goes 'outside' the current VPN tunnel session.

Tor provides functionality to 'anonymize' packet header information (traffic routing information) within the Tor relay network but does not address packet payload encryption/authentication. Tor is routing-centric from a security/privacy standpoint but cannot 'help' once the active connection goes 'outside' the current exit node.

I need to spend some additional time putting together a meaningful use case as per the comment below - please bear with me...

Comment: Um... Why? For all intents and purposes, Tor acts as a VPN inside the browser. Sending traffic through Tor from any other applications would be unique (possibly traceable). What use case are you suggesting here?

Comment: Sorry for the delay  in responding to your post on June 11th.  I have been offline.  Please see my 'thoughts in progress' as appended to my original post...

Comment: Actually, Tor does provide encryption. That's how it works. In my opinion, I don't think Tor should operate as a VPN because that is not its purpose. Right tool for the right job.

Comment: I agree that Tor is not a VPN. But as I understand it, Tor does not 'encrypt' the data payload of its packets nor do I see how it can - it simply provides anonymous TCP transport within the Tor relay network.  VPNs can bring value above and beyond simply using HTTPS.

Comment: Connections in the Tor Network are encrypted. See here: https://www.torproject.org/about/overview and here: https://www.eff.org/pages/tor-and-https

Comment: I read those articles long ago. You are misinterpreting Tor's what to actually does.  From the overview document: Tor 'builds a circuit of encrypted connections' - it doesn't encrypt data being transported. BIG difference. Later on in the document: 'Tor can't solve all anonymity problems. It focuses only on protecting the transport of data. You need to use protocol-specific support software if you don't want the sites you visit to see your identifying information.'  Tor is all about anonymous TCP transport, and does NOTHING to protect the data being tranported.

Comment: The EFF article just describes HTTP/HTTPS 'status' information available in the omnibox and is functionality provided by Firefox and has nothing to do with Tor.

Comment: I'm not sure I can help you understand this better without you digging deeper on your own.  I think you need to better understand VPN functionality and I don't think you can help me further.  Let's consider this discussion closed, OK?

Comment: A VPN doesn't encrypt data either. Once data exits the VPN server, it's left in its original unencrypted form.

Comment: You appear to accept that both TOR and a VPN provide no protection of your data once it's left the TOR exit node/VPN.  But you are mistaken when you say TOR doesn't encrypt data being transported as that is exactly what happens.  Perhaps you've read the wrong articles about TOR?  Read the first paragraph of 4.1 here: https://svn.torproject.org/svn/projects/design-paper/tor-design.html    This explains why you're failing to present a "meaningful use case" and why there's no (need for) an integrated VPN. I mean, it's called an onion router precisely because of the layers of encryption!!

Comment: @alex - Actually, I do have a meaningful use case defined.  My client requires me to get their prior approval before 'publishing' such ideas - its a contractual/IP thing and I don't want to be fired or sued for breach of contract ;)  Once this sanitized version is OK'd, I'll post it.

Comment: @supersluether - It seems to me you are right given a scenario using a public/commercial VPN service that 'hops' through an exit node to access your destination server.  But I think you are wrong given a scenario using a VPN service that has no exit node (i.e., the VPN server 'tunnels' you into the destination server/private network domain).  VPN connections typically use IPsec for end-to-end security at the internet layer

Comment: @supersluether - I'm curious - if your statement " A VPN doesn't encrypt data" were true, why would anyone use a bother to use a VPN?  Isn't that the point of VPNs?  I'm not trying to be nitpicky here, but I think you may be applying a generic, web surfing-type scenario when there is much, much more that VPNs provide.  If I am wrong, I apologize.

Comment: @alex - The Tor design paper (https://svn.torproject.org/svn/projects/design-paper/tor-design.html) is very helpful. It is also 14+ years old - are you aware of any updates this document?

Comment: @alex - The Tor overview document (https://www.torproject.org/about/overview.html.en) - which I had been using as my reference - makes no statement WRT Tor's 128-bit AES cipher encryption and in fact makes a contradictory statements such as "Even if you encrypt the data payload of your communications...", which infers the need to encrypt data. This overview document is so focused on traffic/routing analysis it ignores the relay cell encrypt/decrypt functionality implemented by Tor - an important omission!

Comment: @TL7 The "even if you encrypt" suggests you not only need to encrypt, but you also need to use a system such as TOR, to defeat traffic analysis attacks on your internet usage. If TOR didn't encrypt then the system wouldn't work at all; an attacker could just follow the packets and observe each relay that was involved in a journey from user to exit node and pretty soon they'd find the exit node.  Ie a regular vpn won't protect you in china if chinese authorities detect you connecting to a server which has an ip address allocated to tibet, for example, even if they don't know what you're sending

Comment: And no, I'm not aware of any newer documents. I've always found that odd, and must be a barrier to entry to new developers.  It's as if you have to read the old documents and then look at the source/talk to developers etc to see what's changed since.  I can't imagine it would be a huge task for someone in the know to at least write a document detailing the changes, if not rewrite the original documents from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's technically impossible to keep browser a privacy-oriented and having a VPN support **from within** it. The VPN itself, however, can be elaborated in other network layers - but defenately **not** in browser itself: in a browser you will have an add-on for VPN or something **with** add-on inside. The add-ons list, however, *can be enumerated* and used as a fingerprinting solutions. Also please keep in mind that using even the most trustworthy VPN can result in a very few "exit points" to the Tor network and can be traced. However, using a VPN as an additional way to reach the Tor network is a very good idea

Answer (score 1):

#### [VPNs are *terrible* from an anonymity perspective](https://github.com/epidemics-scepticism/tor-misconception/blob/master/README.md#vpns).

This is my own write-up on the issue, I'm going to address a few specific points of your question too since they are badthink that needs to be purged with fire^Wfacts.

#### "Trusted VPNs".

In information security "Trusted" is bad. Trusted means that you *have* to trust it, it doesn't mean that it is trusty*worthy*. It means that it acts a point of failure, a gamble, since you've no good reason to trust it and it is turns out you were wrong, you lose.

#### "Tor provides functionality to 'anonymize' packet header information"

This is technically incorrect, Tor does not "anonymize" packet header information, it is simply  never transmitted, only the datastream is transmitted.

#### "the Tor [...] network [...] does not address packet payload encryption/authentication"

False. The Tor network uses encrypted, authenticated cells, which may have multiple layers of authenticated encryption applied depending on which part of a circuit they are being sent to, they are also transmitted inside encrypted, authenticated TLS connections between relays inside the network. This claim is entirely bizarre and suggests that your "deep digging" didn't go much beyond the overview page. The data that reaches the exit node cannot be tampered with while within the network, after it *leaves* the network it can be tampered with, but as you yourself point out this is *exactly* the same with a VPN.

#### "[... Spurious bullshit about crypto-magic that you don't understand ...]"

No network (VPN, Tor, whatever else) can make claims for data *once it has left that network*. It *must* be the responsibility of the application which is sending and receiving the data that will leave the network to ensure that it is receives appropriate levels of encryption to ensure confidentiality, integrity and authenticity. There is no alternative.

#### "My client requires me to get their prior approval before 'publishing' such ideas"

If you really do have clients, you should consider providing them a refund and an apology. You really have no idea what you're talking about and, to be frank, you're harming the integrity of the information security industry.